# Trying to upload many pictures from iOS device to Dropbox folder using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, dropbox-api

I have a list in Swift of a bunch of URL from pictures saved in a folder within the iOS device. What happens is that, I want to upload all those pictures to a folder and when I do it I get some pictures and not all. I'm using a loop to do go through every URL and uploading them one by one with in the loop.

Sometimes I get an `http error`. I think this is happening because too many files are being uploaded at the same time. But I don't know how to solve this problem.

```
for p in dbPictures {
    client.files.upload(path: "/\(fileName)/Pictures/\(p.picKey).jpeg", body: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: p.picPath))
}
```

Comment: So load less pictures concurrently, restrict the number of threads it can launch, are your using sessions to upload the photos?

Comment: [Cross-linking for reference: https://www.dropboxforum.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/205763636-trying-to-upload-many-pictures-from-ios-device-to-dropbox-folder-using-swift ]

Comment: no im not using sessions. let me try to look into that. this is the first time im using dropbox api so its a bit hard to understand whats going on. thx